# How to simplify $|1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}|^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm asked to simplify 
$$|1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}|^2.$$
It should be expressed in "real-valued form".

The answer should be

$$\frac{31}{18} - \frac{35}{18}\cos{2\pi f} + \frac{1}{3}\cos{4\pi f}.$$

Comment: Just use the definition $|z|^2 = z z^*$ (where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$), multiply out, simplify and use the equation $(e^{i \theta} + e^{- i \theta})/2 = \cos \theta$, and the corresponding equation for $\sin$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\biggl|1 - \frac{5}{6}\mathrm e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}\mathrm e^{-i4\pi f}\biggr|^2=\biggl(1 - \frac{5}{6}\mathrm e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}\mathrm e^{-i4\pi f}\biggr)\biggl(1 - \frac{5}{6}\mathrm e^{i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}\mathrm e^{i4\pi f}\biggr).$$
Expand and simplify,  then use  that $\;\mathrm e^{ix}+\mathrm e^{-ix}=2\cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, let's denote $a = \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f}$ and $b = -\frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}$. Then the expression we need to evaluate can be written as: $E = |1-a-b|^2 = (1-a-b)(1-a^*-b^*) = 1 + |a|^2 + |b|^2 -2\Re(a)-2\Re(b)+2\Re(ab^*)$. Each of these terms are easy to evaluate individually. Specifically:

1. $|a|^2 = 25/36$
2. $|b|^2 = 1/36$
3. $\Re(a) = \frac{5}{6}\cos(2\pi f)$
4. $\Re(b) = -\frac{1}{6}\cos(4 \pi f)$
5. $\Re(ab^*) = \Re\left( - \frac{5}{36}e^{i2\pi f} \right) = -\frac{5}{36}\cos(2\pi f)$.

Putting together (1)-(5), you will get your desired answer.

Comment: Use `\cos` for the cosine, not `cos`, and `\Re` for the real part, not `\mathbb{R}`.

Comment: @Did Done; thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Write 
\begin{equation}
 1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}
 =
 1 - \frac{5}{6}\cos(2\pi f) + i \frac{5}{6}\sin(2\pi f) +  \frac{1}{6}\cos(4\pi f) - i \frac{1}{6}\sin(4\pi f)
\end{equation}
Collect real and imaginary terms as 
\begin{equation}
 \vert A + i B \vert^2 = A^2 + B^2
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
 A &= 1 - \frac{5}{6}\cos(2\pi f)+  \frac{1}{6}\cos(4\pi f) \\
 B &= \frac{5}{6}\sin(2\pi f) -\frac{1}{6}\sin(4\pi f)
\end{align}
Replace $A$ and $B$,
\begin{equation}
 A^2 + B^2  = (1 - \frac{5}{6}\cos(2\pi f)+  \frac{1}{6}\cos(4\pi f))^2 + (\frac{5}{6}\sin(2\pi f) -\frac{1}{6}\sin(4\pi f))^2
\end{equation}
Can you continue ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$ 1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}
= \frac{1}{6}\left(6-5e^{-i2\pi f}+e^{-i4\pi f} \right)
= \frac{1}{6}\left(3-e^{-i2\pi f}\right)\left(2-e^{-i2\pi f}\right). $$
Now
$$ \left|3-e^{-i2\pi f}\right|^2 = \left|3-\cos(2\pi f) + i\sin(2\pi f)\right|^2 = (3-\cos(2\pi f))^2 + \sin^2(2\pi f) = 10 - 6\cos(2\pi f), $$
and
$$ \left|2-e^{-i2\pi f}\right|^2 = \left|2-\cos(2\pi f) + i\sin(2\pi f)\right|^2 = (2-\cos(2\pi f))^2 + \sin^2(2\pi f) = 5 - 4\cos(2\pi f), $$
so that
\begin{align}
\left| 1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-i4\pi f}\right|^2
&= \frac{1}{36}\left| 6 - 5e^{-i2\pi f} + e^{-i4\pi f}\right|^2\\
&= \frac{1}{36}\left|3-e^{-i2\pi f}\right|^2\left|2-e^{-i2\pi f}\right|^2\\
&= \frac{1}{36}(10-6\cos(2\pi f))(5 - 4\cos(2\pi f))\\
&= \frac{1}{18}(25-35\cos(2\pi f) + 12\cos^2(2\pi f)).
\end{align}
To get your final form, you can use the fact that
\begin{align}
&\cos(4\pi f) = \cos(2\cdot 2\pi f) = \cos^2(2\pi f) - \sin^2(2\pi f) = 2\cos^2(2\pi f ) - 1\\ &\iff \cos^2(2\pi f) = \frac{\cos(4\pi f) + 1}{2}
\end{align}